# Pop-Up Blocker and Flex's PopUpManager

Tags: apache-flex, popup

This is a rather simple question. I need to confirm. (So don't flame me, please).

If a user has a pop-up blocker on, will it effect pop-ups within a Flex application. If I use the PopUpManager class in my app, is there the possibility that it would be blocked. (I'm writing about pop-ups within the app, not advertising pop-ups and pop-unders.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PopUpManager applies only to flex, the browser's pop up mechanisms have absolutely no bearing on the PopUpManager class since it displays "pop ups" entirely within the bounds of the application's browser window.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Wade. That's what I thought, but better safe than sorry.